# Save position in UIImagePickerController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I am developing an app which allows you to select photos and place them into different positions. The workflow is basically:

1. Tap an area of the screen
2. `UIImagePickerController` displays
3. Select a photo
4. Photo displays in the tapped area of the screen

I would like it so that if the user goes through this workflow for a second time, the `UIImagePickerController` when displayed will be showing the same album, and position within that album, that the user was last at.

I've tried saving a reference to the `UIImagePickerController`, as well as the `UIPopoverController`, so that they are created only once. However, every time I present the popover containing the `UIImagePickerController`, it is back at the main photos menu (eg. Camera Roll, Photo Library, My Photo Stream).

Any ideas for how to achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Have you checked if Asset library can be used instead of UIImagePickerController and customize according to your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to point you to right direction. You can use asset library to show the images as a picker. You can use the apple sample code [MyImagePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135). The method `[[assetsLibrary] enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAlbum usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)` can be used for photo album. Using the asset library you can check which image was selected last and then use the method,

```
- (void)enumerateAssetsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexSet options:(NSEnumerationOptions)options usingBlock:(ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock)enumerationBlock;
```

You can use this method next time to enumerate which image onwards you want to enumerate. This method can accept an indexSet as `[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(index, count)]` which should help to indicate the last selected image.

To know more about [how to use asset library check this](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/accessing-photo-library-using-assets-library-framework-on-iphone/).

Comment: Thanks, apologies for the delay in accepting the answer. Enjoy your well deserved bounty!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ALAssetsLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) . But this will cost you more effort. First time use `– enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:` to list all album and remember user's choice. And at second time. Just use that album:`ALAssetsGroup`'s `– enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:` to list all the images and videos. Apple has a few demo you can have a look [PhotosByLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotosByLocation/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010136) [MyImagePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MyImagePicker/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010135)

Answer (score 1):

keep a `UIImagePickerController` obj in .h class (for example `imagePicker`)

alloc the obj once (for example in `viewDidLoad`)

```
imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self; 
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];
imagePicker.view.hidden = YES;
imagePicker.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
imagePicker.view.bounds  = CGRectMake(0,20,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
```

In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`

```
if([[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] isEqualToString:@"public.image"]){
    imagePicker.view.hidden = YES;
}
```

When you want to show the `imagePickerView` just do

```
imagePicker.view.hidden = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to reach into the resulting `UITableView` and then find its content offset. You can do this by searching the subviews of the `UIImagePickerController`'s `view` property for a table view.

```
for (UIView *view in controller.view) {
  if ([view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
    contentOffset = [(UITableView *)view contentOffset];
  }
}
```

When you represent the view controller, you will want to restore the content offset in a similar fashion.

Note, I haven't actually tested to see the view hierarchy of the `UIImagePickerController`. Verify its structure by printing its subviews. There is also no guarantee that the structure will stay the same, since you are diving into the private implementation (though it's important to note you are not actually using any private APIs so this is okay).

Comment: Hmm interesting idea but not really sure if it would work in practice, as I can't see any way to also store & select the album that the user was in? If it was just a single screen of photos that would be fine, but it's not - the user first selects the album, then a photo.

Comment: while there is no private API usage here, the content hierarchy of `UIImagePickerController` is considered "private", and you should not depend on it. This solution works for now, but will break if Apple changes the structure of `UIImagePickerController` (by e.g. using `UICollectionView` instead, which is very likely). In short, you're not supposed to be able to manipulate this view. Roll your own image picker instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Use AlAssetsLibrary. It control the image & video capture under the application. there a demo on apple.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

look for this or

if you want to make a cutomize album for the image and video here a great example.

https://github.com/Kjuly/ALAssetsLibrary-CustomPhotoAlbum